# Dokku: Not seeing container port

Tags: docker, nginx, dokku

Calling out for a little Dokku help here, if anyone has some knowledge of it. I've built a new Dokku server and am trying to deploy a pre-existing app. I know the app is good, because it's running on another dokku host with no problem.

When I deploy the app on this server, it returns a single address... which is not valid. It's the hostname of the box, which is fine. I don't expect that to work. But the point is, when I deploy to the other (working) dokku host, it returns two URL's. One for `nginx` and one for `container`, when when I navigate to the container port (which is random every deployment, probably because of conflicting ports when containers coexist), I get to see the app.

This tells me that nginx proxy is off, and the container is bound to an external interface on the dokku host, right?

So, on the new server if I run `dokku proxy:disable app`, and then run `docker ps` I don't see anything bound under ports.

```
[root@dokku-host ~]# dokku proxy:disable fr-intacct-staging
-----> Disabling proxy for app (fr-intacct-staging)
-----> Setting config vars
       DOKKU_DISABLE_PROXY:  1
-----> Unsetting DOKKU_PROXY_PORT
-----> Skipping DOKKU_PROXY_SSL_PORT, it is not set in the environment
-----> Unsetting DOKKU_PROXY_PORT_MAP
-----> VHOST support disabled, deleting fr-intacct-staging/VHOST
-----> VHOST support disabled, deleting fr-intacct-staging/URLS
-----> Setting config vars
       NO_VHOST:  1
-----> Releasing fr-intacct-staging (dokku/fr-intacct-staging:latest)...
-----> Deploying fr-intacct-staging (dokku/fr-intacct-staging:latest)...
-----> App Procfile file found (/home/dokku/fr-intacct-staging/DOKKU_PROCFILE)
-----> DOKKU_SCALE file found (/home/dokku/fr-intacct-staging/DOKKU_SCALE)
=====> web=1
-----> Attempting pre-flight checks
       For more efficient zero downtime deployments, create a file CHECKS.
       See http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/zero-downtime-deploys/ for examples
       CHECKS file not found in container: Running simple container check...
-----> Waiting for 10 seconds ...
-----> Default container check successful!
-----> Running post-deploy
-----> VHOST support disabled. Skipping domains setup
-----> nginx support is disabled for app (fr-intacct-staging).
-----> deleting nginx.conf
-----> reloading nginx after nginx.conf deletion
-----> Setting config vars
       DOKKU_APP_RESTORE:  1
-----> Found previous container(s) (9f0d2416e9ed) named fr-intacct-staging.web.1
=====> Renaming container (9f0d2416e9ed) fr-intacct-staging.web.1 to fr-intacct-staging.web.1.1550048431
=====> Renaming container (d9f6006f0eaf) naughty_cartwright to fr-intacct-staging.web.1
-----> Shutting down old containers in 60 seconds
=====> 9f0d2416e9ed1f44716e16b3f39236cde9d0d5594bb60c0823dee0053d49e6f8
=====> Application deployed:
       http://dokku-host.c.fr-intacct-staging.internal:5000 (container)
```

So if I test from a browser to the public IP of that box, on port 5000 I don't see the app (fw open all the way), but if I check port 80 I do see the nginx holding page. So nginx is running on port 80, I'd expect to see the app running on port 5000?

I see this:
[root@dokku-host ~]# docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
d9f6006f0eaf        dokku/fr-intacct-staging:latest   "/start web"        4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                            fr-intacct-staging.web.1
```

Nothing seems to be bound to an external interface. Surely I'd expect to see something like `0.0.0.0/0:5000` there, no?

I'm new to Dokku, but have some Docker experience.

EDIT: Just some extra info...

From the old host:

```
root@dokku:/home/dokku/fr-intacct# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
5fbd53343888        dokku/fr-intacct:latest   "/start web"        5 months ago        Up 5 months         0.0.0.0:32792->5000/tcp   fr-intacct.web.1

 root@dokku:/home/dokku/fr-intacct# dokku config fr-intacct
=====> fr-intacct config vars
DOKKU_APP_RESTORE: 1
DOKKU_NGINX_PORT:  80
NO_VHOST:          1 

 root@dokku:/home/dokku/fr-intacct# dokku urls fr-intacct
http://dokku.internal.fr.com:32792 (container)
http://dokku.internal.fr.com:80 (nginx)
```

From the new host:

```
[root@dokku-host fr-intacct-staging]# docker ps 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
d9f6006f0eaf        dokku/fr-intacct-staging:latest   "/start web"        14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes                           fr-intacct-staging.web.1
[root@dokku-host fr-intacct-staging]# dokku config fr-intacct-staging
=====> fr-intacct-staging env vars
DOKKU_APP_RESTORE:    1
DOKKU_APP_TYPE:       herokuish
DOKKU_DISABLE_PROXY:  1
GIT_REV:              337bd92c233fc6b7e17246bf568fc30370d3e656
NO_VHOST:             1
[root@dokku-host fr-intacct-staging]# dokku urls fr-intacct-staging
http://dokku-host.c.fr-intacct-staging.internal:5000 (container)
```

I have tried making the config settings the same with `dokku config set fr-intacct-staging xxxx=xxx`, to no avail.

My gut feeling is that I need to stop it from trying to use nginx as a proxy, bind the container to external interfaces and connect directly to the container.

However:

```
[root@dokku-host fr-intacct-staging]# dokku proxy:disable fr-intacct-staging
-----> proxy is already disable for app (fr-intacct-staging)
[root@dokku-host fr-intacct-staging]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
d9f6006f0eaf        dokku/fr-intacct-staging:latest   "/start web"        35 minutes ago      Up 35 minutes                           fr-intacct-staging.web.1
[root@dokku-host fr-intacct-staging]#
```

Really would appreciate thoughts on this... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This was easily resolvable with help from Dokku support over in Slack. I was referencing an older doc.

Resolution to this was:

```
dokku proxy:disable fr-intacct-staging
dokku network:set fr-intacct-staging bind-all-interfaces true
dokku ps:rebuild fr-intacct-staging
```

Docs here are great: http://dokku.viewdocs.io 
But.. make sure to select the version in the bottom right. The differences between versions are vast.